# WCF Error - Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am consuming a WCF service which has two functions, `GetAllProducts()` to return all products and `GetProductById(int id)` to return one product.

`GetAllProducts()` returns all data and `GetProductById()` does not return anything and produces this error.

There shouldn't be any problem within the WCF service communication itself as `GetAllProducts()` is returning data. Does any one have any idea ?

ERROR :

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://XX.XXX:92/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IData.GetProductById(Int32 ProductId)
   at DataClient.GetProductById(Int32 ProductId)

Inner Exception:
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

Inner Exception:
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

Inner Exception:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

Comment: Debug the server side. When you still have a question, include the relevant source code.

Comment: When debugged in WCF service, the data is returned. But when it reaches client, I am getting the error.

Comment: The most possible cause is problems within Xml deserializer. So check your classes Entity_Product.

Comment: @KarelKral List<Entity_Product> is not an issue with GetAllProducts(), so it should be the same case for just Entity_Product right ?

Comment: Provide `GetAllProduct()` signature and `Entity_Product` model here.

Comment: Have you tried to look in WCF-logs? They can often help you out, take a look here to know how to enable logging:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/configuring-message-logging

Comment: @Aria Updated !!

Comment: Decorate `Entity_Product` by `[DataContract]` and all of it's properties by `[DataMember]` and see what happened.

Comment: @Aria Same error after adding datacontract and datamember for the entity

Comment: This may have several reasons, which is hard to know the clue, it may depends on `binding` depends on `serializing` even returned data or etc, client side configuration.

Comment: @Aria Ok! Now I have added the full error details from WCF Test client. Please let me know if you find any clue

Comment: It may related to message size, increase them in `binding` configuration file, change them in client and server configuration, like  `maxBufferSize="2000000000" maxBufferPoolSize="2000000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000"`

Comment: you have 2 child entities and my guess is that GetAllProducts don't fill these child entities. I would say, remove them for initial testing and see if that works

Comment: Please try to decorate the entity with [Datacontract], which binding you use to create the service? how do you call the service?